# Apache Spark MLlib LabeledPoint null label issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, logistic-regression, apache-spark-mllib

I'm trying to run one of MLlib algorithms, namely LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS on my database.

This algorithm takes the training set as LabeledPoint. Since LabeledPoint requires a double label ( LabeledPoint( double label, Vector features) ) and my database contains some null values, how can I solve this problem?

Here you can see the piece of code related to this issue :

```
val labeled = table.map{ row => 
    var s = row.toSeq.toArray           
    s = s.map(el => if (el != null) el.toString.toDouble)
    LabeledPoint(row(0), Vectors.dense((s.take(0) ++ s.drop(1))))
    }
```

And the error that I get:

```
error   : type mismatch;
found   : Any
required: Double
```

Without using LabeledPoint can I run this algorithm or how can I overcome this "null value" issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some reasons why this code cannot work:

- `Row.toSeq` is of type `() => Seq[Any]` and so is `s`
- since you cover only not null case `el => if (el != null) el.toString.toDouble` is of type `T => AnyVal` (where `T` is any). If `el` is `null` it returns `Unit`
- even if it wasn't you assign it to `var` of type `Seq[Any]` this is exactly what you get. One way or another it is not a valid input for `Vectors.dense`
- `Row.apply` is of type `Int => Any` so the output cannot be used as a label

Should work but have no effect:

- `s.take(0)`

May stop working in Spark 2.0

- `map` over `DataFrame` - not much we can do about it now since `Vector` class has no encoder available.

How you can approach this:

- either filter complete rows or fill missing values for example using `DataFrameNaFunctions`:

  ```
    // You definitely want something smarter than that
    val fixed = df.na.fill(0.0)
    // or
    val filtered = df.na.drop
  ```
- use `VectorAssembler` to build vectors:

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler

  val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(df.columns.tail)
    .setOutputCol("features")

  val assembled = assembler.transform(fixed)
  ```
- convert to `LabledPoint`

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint  


  // Assuming lable column is called label

  assembled.select($"label", $"features").rdd.map {
    case Row(label: Double, features: Vector) => 
      LabeledPoint(label, features)
  }
  ```